# Can I use memoization to cache data in the hbase read and write from spark job?

Tags: scala, hbase, spark-streaming, user-defined-functions, memoization

In a Scala project which has a Spark job, I used Spark-Hbase connector (SHC) to connect read from Hbase data.
The number of requests are very large and I am trying to use cached data for a certain amount of time. I am wondering if I can do that. Maybe Memoization can help?!

Comment: How about defining the problem better? Caching Hbase is not recommended as you state. Typically too large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

[HBase itself provides two different kinds of cache](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#block.cache).

A way to cache data into Spark is using [Pair RDDs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs).

You can also use [Broadcast variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)

About memoization, remember that it is local to the single node. So you can have data memoized on a node and have cache miss on all other nodes.